# Objective C +(id) methods

Tags: objective-c

I am quite new to Objective-C in some ways, so I'd like to ask how should I make methods that return the objects themselves. Let me show an example:

In `NSArray` you can do `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:bla,bla,nil];`

How I make that kind of method to my own class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two main things going on with that method:

1. It's a Class method (ie, a `+` method)
2. It uses a variable argument list

To make it, you'd probably do something like this:

```
+ (id)fooWithStuff:(id)stuff, ... NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION {
  // the "+" means it's a class method
  // the "NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION" is so that the compiler knows you have to use it like this:
  // foo = [ThisClass fooWithStuff:thing1, thing2, thing3, nil];
  // (IOW, there must be a "nil" at the end of the list)

  va_list args;  // declare a "variable list"
  va_start(args, stuff);  // the list starts after the "stuff" argument

  Foo *foo = [[Foo alloc] init];  // create a Foo object

  id nextStuff = stuff;  // this is the next stuff
  while(nextStuff != nil) { // while there is more stuff...
    [foo doSomethingWithStuff:nextStuff];  // do something with the stuff
    nextStuff = va_arg(args, id);  // get the next stuff in the list
    // the "id" means that you're asking for something the size of a pointer
  }
  va_end(args);  // close the argument list

  return [foo autorelease];  // return the Foo object

}
```

Comment: Now I get it thanks so much! I always wondered why I have to put nil to the end!

Comment: @Samuli yep, the `nil` is so that the list knows when to stop.  It's called the "sentinel" :)